# Problem with tablebases

Tags: engines, tablebases

I hope this is the right forum for my question.

So, I have all 5 men files on my HDD and the two files

KRPPvKR.rtbz

KRPPvKR.rtbw

In the position here (8/2K2k2/3R3P/5P2/8/8/8/r7 w - - 0 10) everything looks good.

Image 1[image]

But if I play the move 10.h7, Angie starts calculating. Stockfisch is right, 10... Kg7 is a draw, but something is wrong.

Does anyone have an idea why the engine starts calculating here?

picture 2
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have those files then the engine needs to calculate positions that are not in the files.  In your case I expect it is calculating the effects of pawn promotion which would need to understand positions with a queen, bishop, knight, or additional rook.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the other files, Now everything works fine.

Comment: @newbie glad to hear it worked out.  Would you care to accept my answer?